# how to run a shell script using prometheus-am-executor

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have downloaded the prometheus-am-executor-0.0.1.zip available on internet.

Can someone please help me with the below queries. I'm unable to setup this exporter.

1. How to start this exporter ?
2. What we need to configure for this exporter to receive alert from alertmanager ?
3. What we need to configure for this exporter to run a script or command.
4. what is the difference between alertmanager.conf and alertmanager.yaml which we have setup to receive alerts from alertmanager.

Thanks
Priyotosh

Answer (score 2):

> How to start this exporter ?

This is not an exporter. This is a simple HTTP server that can receive an alert from the alertmanager and invoke a script.

This server can be started with the command:

```
./prometheus-am-executor script.sh
```

Where `script.sh` is the script that you want to be called once the alertmanager sends the alert notification.

> What we need to configure for this exporter to receive alert from alertmanager ?

When you start the executor using the command above, it will listen on port 8080 for notification from the alertmanager. You don't need to configure anything for the executor.

> What we need to configure for this exporter to run a script or command

Just pass the script file that needs to executed as described in the command above.

> what is the difference between alertmanager.conf and alertmanager.yaml
>   which we have setup to receive alerts from alertmanager.

The alertmanager.conf is an example of the alertmanager.yaml. It is provided as a sample to illustrate how you can trigger the executor. The relevant part is:

```
- name: 'executor'
  webhook_configs:
  - url: http://localhost:8080
```

This is configuring a receiver called `executor` that will notify a server listening on `localhost:8080` which in this case is the executor.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. However when I extract the prometheus-am-executor-0.0.1.zip i can't see any executable like ./prometheus-am-executor which can start a Http server and invoke a script.

Comment: can we use python scrip too ? If yes then can you please give us an example where you have extracted alert variable in python.